# The product of step functions is an step function?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, lebesgue-integral

i have a question about demostration of the properties of step functions, if i have two functions with they standar representation $\phi=\sum a_iX_{A_i}$ and $\psi=\sum b_jX_{A_j}$ and i do a partition taking the union of finite intervals of $\phi$ and $\psi$, such that  $\phi=\sum c_rX_{A_{c_r}}$ and $\psi=\sum d_rX_{A_{c_r}}$, the product is:

$\psi \phi=\sum c_rX_{A_{c_r}} \sum d_rX_{A_{c_r}}....(*)$ 
How can i argue that (*) is the same that 
$\psi \phi=\sum c_rd_rX_{A_{c_r}} $
because the product of sums are not equals. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, $X_{A}X_{B} = X_{A\cap B}$. In the case of partitions, the only non-zero products are given when $A=B$.

Comment: Oh! it's true, for $r\neq k$ al products are zero, I had not noticed, thanks for the support. Regards.